# Читать из static коллекции List безопасно?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, .net-core

Есть код к которому происходит обращение из разных потоков, но только чтение, в нашем случае мы используем функцию contains на листе `SupportedContentTypes`:

```cs
internal class HttpRequestConst
{
    public static readonly List<string> SupportedContentTypes = new List<string> { "application/json" };
}
```

Вопрос какие могут возникать проблемы при вызове

```cs
HttpRequestConst.SupportedContentTypes.Contains("some text")
```

из разных потоков?

Comment: если содержимое не меняется - чтение безопасно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874317/thread-safe-listt-property Из чего выходит что List<T> не безопасен к потокам. `System.Collections.Concurrent`.`ConcurrentBag<T>` - безопасен к потокам.

Comment: @EugeneX а если коллекция не меняется и мы из нее только читаем?

Comment: Проблема потоков том, что они могут изменить одно и тоже значение несколько раз. Допустим запускаете вы 3 потока, где каждый должен сделать +1 к некой `int count`, вы ожидаете на выходе 3, но получаете всегда разное значение (1, 2, 3), почему? А потому, что несколько потоков сразу могут взять одно значения (допустим 1) и сделать дважды `1+1` присвоив это. С коллекциями +- аналогично, если меняете потоками - можете получить не то, что ожидаете. С чтением теперь подумайте сами, что будет если 2 потока получат одно статичное значение, которое не меняется в процессе выполнения программы? Ничего.